# MySQL is outputting binary hex strings that somehow resolve into text. How does this work?

Tags: mysql

I'm using a GUI MySQL manager called Sequel Pro on my Mac.

Historically, when I'd right-click a row and click "Copy as SQL Insert", it would copy a standard-looking MySQL insert statement containing the row contents **in plain text**.

I noticed the other day when doing this, the output now looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO `config` (`key`, `value`)
VALUES
    (X'68656C6C6F5F737461636B5F6F766572666C6F77', X'5468616E6B7320666F7220616E73776572696E67206D79207175657374696F6E');
```

What is with the random letter/number strings beginning with `X`? Starting a string with an `X` doesn't look like standard SQL syntax. Somehow though, when I run the SQL command it enters a valid new record with the data I would expect into the table.

What feature is this, what benefit does it serve, and why did it suddenly change since last week?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a SQL standard to escape binary literals in the format:

```
x'hexstring'
```

Like the following:

```
x'68656C6C6F5F737461636B5F6F766572666C6F77'
```

According to a comment on the documentation for the [BINARY and VARBINARY Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/binary-varbinary.html), MySQL also supports the ODBC standard:

```
0x68656C6C6F5F737461636B5F6F766572666C6F77
```